# Watching a DVD 14.04.1 Thinkpad T410

Tags: dvd

OK so I have the 'restricted extras' installed and have run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4    
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Still can't view a region 2 DVD in VLC Player or Videos. I get a read error in Videos and nothing happens in VLC. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu so fear I may be missing something obvious. Any help or guidance would be very welcome?

Comment: What was the outcome of `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`? Was it successful? Were there any error messages? What region is your DVD drive set to (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Setting_DVD_Region_Codes)? You can [edit] you question to improve it with additional info.

Comment: No, no errors in response to that command. I am unable to set the region using the sudo regionset, it tells me that it is unable to read the disc when I try that command. I have tried it with several different discs which I know to be OK-well they run OK in my Mac! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Maybe the DVD is indeed physically unreadable. Do the DVDs that you know to work on Mac OS or Windows work in Ubuntu?

Comment: Well so far no they don't work in Ubuntu. Is it possible that commercial DVDs that work on other platforms are unplayable on Ubuntu? If that were the problem you would think I might find one  that would play in Ubuntu, wouldn't you? Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. This is definitely a region issue. As far as I understand the citation in the [Ubuntu Wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Setting_DVD_Region_Codes), some device firmwares don't implement regions correctly.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant but when I try to run the 'regionset' command I get 'ERROR: Could not open disc "(null)"! Please ensure there is a readable CD or DVD in the drive'

Comment: Well, did you put a video DVD in the drive?

Comment: Yes I have tried a few different discs. Thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: I guess you also ran `regionset` as superuser (e. g. with `sudo`)? And just to make sure: Is there a search result for `find /usr/lib -name libdvdcss.so\*`?

Comment: Looks to be in order. I'm out of ideas again.

Comment: Yes did `sudo regionset` as well. That search throws up this result `usr/lib/libdvdcss.so.2 usr/libdvdcss.so.2.1.0`? Interestingly VLC does now launch the DVD and play it but the image is extremely pixelated and broken up. Not aware that I have changed anything though!

Comment: Thanks David, you've been very patient and helpful. It's frustrating as I'm obviously quite close!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I seem to have resolved the issue for me!:)

I deleted the `~/.dvdcss` folder. (For the unitiated like me, that means it's in your home folder, but also be aware you will need to show the hidden files in order to see it.)

From my limited understanding, it seems that if you try a disc and it doesn't work first time you will need to delete this file or your player will always try to use the wrong encryption code.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to wait some time for libdvdcss to crack the DVDs encryption. If you encounter other errors, refer to

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: When you say 'some time' do you mean minutes, hours? And I need to leave it with a disc in the drive presumably, but do I need to leave an application open such as VLC or Videos?

Comment: Leave vlc open, if it takes more than 5 minutes OR you see no rise in cpu/gpu usage by libdvdcss or vlc player, something else is wrong.

Comment: Tried that with VLC with no luck. Clearly something else is wrong.:( Thanks for trying to help though!